# Loop background-img and background-color with less

Tags: loops, less

I'm trying to loop both a image and color as a background for a set of divs. I can loop out different images with the help of less but not the colors. I have tried a number of methods without any success. This is my working code, can anyone see what I can do to add the colors.

```
@num-icons: 13;
@icon_color_1: #7FB3D4;
@icon_color_2: #767676;
@icon_color_3: #8CC079;
@icon_color_4: #b35d5d;
@icon_color_5: #b5473e;
@icon_color_6: #666;
@icon_color_7: #81BABD;
@icon_color_8: #AEA7CF;
@icon_color_9: #b5473e;
@icon_color_10: #666;
@icon_color_11: #81BABD;
@icon_color_12: #AEA7CF;


.loop(@i) when (@i > 0) {
    @tile-value: @i - 1;
    .icon_@{i} {
      background-image: url('@{images}icons/icon_@{i}.svg');
    }


  .loop((@i - 1));
}

.loop(@num-icons);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to emulate arrays via variable names. Less has native array support:

```css
@icon-colors: 
    #7FB3D4,
    #767676,
    #8CC079,
    #b35d5d,
    #b5473e,
       #666,
    #81BABD,
    #AEA7CF,
    #b5473e,
       #666,
    #81BABD,
    #AEA7CF;


.generate-icons(@i: length(@icon-colors)) when (@i > 0) {
    .generate-icons((@i - 1));
    .icon_@{i} {
        background-color: extract(@icon-colors, @i);
        background-image: url('@{images}icons/icon_@{i}.svg');
    }
}

.generate-icons();
```